# Rendering emails with handlebars in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, email-templates

I am writing application using Nodejs/express/hbs/handlebars.

I try to send e-mails to user, after purchase, with receipt.  It should be just simple text message, with invoice entries and total value.

Sending email works well, and I can render simple values like `{{buyers_email}}`, but when comes to using `{{#each }} ... {{/each}}` - it doesn't render it, it just prints it literally to email's content.

It is even weirder, because in normal pages (like index.hbs), the `{#each}` is used, and it works well.

Here goes the code:

**server.coffee**

```
  sendReceipt = (buyers_email) ->
    products =  [
      { name: 'Product1', name: 'Joan' }
      { name: 'Product2', name: 'Cesar' }
    ]
    mailer.send
      host: xxx
      port: xxx
      authentication: 'login'
      username: xxx
      password: xxx
      domain:xxx
      from: xxx
      to: buyers_email
      subject: xxx
      template: 'views/email-receipt.hbs'
      data:
        products: products
        some_key: "some value"
    , (err)-> {}
```

**email-receipt.hbs**

```
<p>{{some_key}}</p>
{{#each products}}
  <p>product</p>
{{/each}}
```

and the result is:

```
some_value 
{{#each products}} product {{/each}}
```

What can cause such a behaviour?

Comment: If you just manually render the template with the data, does that work? What does `mailer.send` do?

Comment: @WiredPrairie, what do you mean by manually render? I have corrected the server.coffee indendation, it should be clearer now.

Mailer.send just sends email, it's that library: https://github.com/Marak/node_mailer

Comment: Call the handlebars render function directly.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, when made this way:  http://pastebin.com/2wz0QJjB it works. Should I call handlebars render somehow in email template?

Comment: Could you try `{{#each data.products}}`? You didn't mention which mailer package you're using.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, I tried, the results are same. This is the mailer I am using: https://github.com/Marak/node_mailer . I can change to another mailer, it by it I could use simple templates with each loop.

Comment: The package you pointed to says its a dead project and that the project was merged with https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer.